# How to catch and display stacktrace for java.lang.RuntimeException using JPype

Tags: java, python

I am trying to call a Java library using Jpype. My java code is throwing NullPointerException, but I not able to print stacktrace. I tried the method given in the tutorial http://jpype.sourceforge.net/doc/user-guide/userguide.html , but its not working.

Any ideas ?

Comment: When you say you are not able to printStackTrace do you mean, you are not able to catch the exception via the pype code?

Comment: I am able to catch the exception, but it is not java.lang.NullPointerException. By calling javaClass() method on the exception object I am getting a class object, but not sure how to get the java object.

Comment: Control does not even go inside the except block.

Comment: Force a throw within the try block to see if you will fall into except.

Answer (score 2):

In the version of JPype that I'm using ([0.5.4.2 from Ubuntu Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-jpype)), the API is different from that which is documented on the JPype website (your link).  I can get a stack trace like this:

```
import jpype
...
try:
    doSomething()
except jpype.JavaException as exception:
    print exception.message()
    print exception.stacktrace()
```

Note that the stacktrace method has no capital "T" and it is called on the instance, not the class, unlike the documentation.